# interactive list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, listview

What's the name of the list html form element like the one found [here](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/)?

Does anyone know of a jquery plugin to achieve something like this where you select Desktop and the next list prepopulates with info specific to the selected option?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Why don't you use Firebug to inspect how it works?

Comment: because its a <dl> and i looks like a hack to me rather than a standard html element

Comment: Really? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dl.asp

Comment: right. since when a ListView has been a definition list?

Answer (score 2):

This is [`<dl>` - definition list](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dl.asp), with some css styles according to [css table](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/new/css/dlc.css)

Comment: that looks like a hack to me? i thought there was a standard html listview element?

Comment: This is not a hack - just styles for this element. What do mean by `Standard listview element`?